# 33 Rep and Editor Badge?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, editor

How is it that someone with 33 rep can have the editor badge?

EDIT: My apologies.  As soon as I posted this I got that badge and realized it didn't mean only other peoples posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing one of their *own* posts will do it.

Comment: yup. I edited one of my own posts, even just one minute after posting it, and I got the Editor badge for that...+1