# Editor badge awarded to inactive user after moderator edited his post

Tags: discussion

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412633/ariel-szk?tab=activity) was last seen over year ago (Aug 6 '10 at 3:51) however 30 minutes ago he [received the editor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor?userid=412633) for his post that was edited by a moderator.

Is this a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 4):

He had edited his own question, so I would think that is where his badge is coming from. It looks like the system simply didn't pick up that edit before and give him the badge.

Not picking up the old edit and giving him the badge sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Editing your own post does give you that badge, according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66962/33-rep-and-editor-badge.  Corrected your post for you; hope you don't mind.

Comment: @KevinVermeer - Much appreciated :)

Comment: Hmm... think I got it. The badge is awarded next time you visit the site - he probably edited, left and never came back. [Merging his accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117883/merging-of-two-accounts) probably triggered this as if he visited again, awarding the badge. If this can be confirmed by a moderator I'll post it as answer but not sure yet.